# Not all Intel is visible

Tags: the-division

Once you get the canine unit in the security wing, it unlocks the perk to see Intel locations on the map. Granted you have completed all the side missions in the zone.

Is there a limitation to this as I cannot see anymore Intel on the map, but I am missing a significant portion of them still. Or are there potentially DLC exclusive Intel? I guess I can run around the entire map, but I wasn't sure if there was something I'm missing.

I have completed all side missions (Still have some encounters up). All main missions are done.

Comment: It's been a long time, but you might need to finish all the encounters to see the intel in that zone. Somewhere in the menu it will say which zones you still need intel in. Do those zones match the zones where you still have encounters to do?

Comment: @Adeese I can start doing them to see but I don't think encounters change it sadly.. And the zones with intel still missing are spread out across most of them

Answer (score 2):

According to the skill description (which you can see [HERE](http://thedivision.wikia.com/wiki/Intel_Discovery)):

> When completing all **Side Missions** and **Encounters** in a Named Zone,
>   reveal all undiscovered Intel on the map.

So, *Intel Discovery* requires that you complete everything in a zone before all intel is shown to you.